# if statement comparing dates with in pandas

Tags: pandas, date, if-statement

I have this dataframe (forec_pivot2):

```
data = {'Month': ['2023-11','2023-12','2024-01','2024-02','2024-03','2024-04','2024-05','2024-06',], 
'EU': [30,  40 , 29 , 25 , 27 , 27 , 37 , 29], 
'Japan': [310,  60 , 60 , 60 , 60 , 50 , 350 , 49], 
'MTO': [400,  0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0], 
'ROW': [2206,  1794 , 3185 , 1683 , 2281 , 2240 , 2226 , 2418], 
'Month_date': ['2023-11-01',  '2023-12-01' , '2024-01-01' , '2024-02-01' , '2024-03-01' , '2024-04-01' , '2024-05-01' , '2024-06-01'] }

forec_pivot2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

forec_pivot2["Month_date"] = pd.to_datetime(forec_pivot2["Month_date"])
```

And I want to make different calculations based on the Month_date value I have (8 months):

```
import datetime
d1 = pd.to_datetime('2024-02-01')

list_0=[]
list_1=[]

    for i in range(8):
        if forec_pivot2.loc[i,'Month_date'] < d1:
            result=forec_pivot2.loc[i,'Japan']+forec_pivot2.loc[i,'MTO']
            list_0.append(result)
        else:
            result2=forec_pivot2.loc[i,'Japan']+forec_pivot2.loc[i,'MTO']+forec_pivot2.loc[i,'ROW']
            list_1.append(result2)

final_list = list_0 + list_1
forec_pivot2['new_col'] = final_list
```

The problem is that is not letting me compare each date (forec_pivot2.loc[i,'Month_date']) with the given value I'm trying to set as threshold.

Can you help me here?

```
for i in range(36):
    if forec_pivot2.loc[i,'Month_date'] < d1:
        result=forec_pivot2.loc[i,'Japan']+forec_pivot2.loc[i,'MTO']
        list_0.append(result)
    else:
        result2=forec_pivot2.loc[i,'Japan']+forec_pivot2.loc[i,'MTO']+forec_pivot2.loc[i,'ROW']
        list_1.append(result)
```

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm starting here.

Comment: Thanks for updating, the question is a lot clearer now. For the sample data you have provided, could you please [edit] your question with your expected output.

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it? Otherwise, please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You are likely facing issues because the 'Month_date' column in your DataFrame is not in datetime format. You need to convert this column to datetime before you can make the comparison with d1. It should look like this:

```
forec_pivot2['Month_date'] = pd.to_datetime(forec_pivot2['Month_date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')

d1 = datetime.datetime(2024, 10, 1)

list_0 = []
list_1 = []

for i in range(len(forec_pivot2)):
    if forec_pivot2.loc[i,'Month_date'] < d1:
        result = forec_pivot2.loc[i,'Japan'] + forec_pivot2.loc[i,'MTO']
        list_0.append(result)
    else:
        result2 = forec_pivot2.loc[i,'Japan'] + forec_pivot2.loc[i,'MTO'] + forec_pivot2.loc[i,'ROW']
        list_1.append(result2)

final_list = list_0 + list_1
forec_pivot2['new_col'] = final_list
```

Comment: Hello, 

I'm afraid that is not the problem. These are the types:


Key
Month                  object
Trade Name             object
EU                    float64
Japan                 float64
MTO                   float64
ROW                   float64
Nom Potency             int64
All_ROW               float64
Month_date     datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me (with pandas 2.0.1), I get as output:

```
     Month  EU  Japan  MTO   ROW Month_date  new_col
0  2023-11  30    310  400  2206 2023-11-01      710
1  2023-12  40     60    0  1794 2023-12-01       60
2  2024-01  29     60    0  3185 2024-01-01       60
3  2024-02  25     60    0  1683 2024-02-01     1743
4  2024-03  27     60    0  2281 2024-03-01     2341
5  2024-04  27     50    0  2240 2024-04-01     2290
6  2024-05  37    350    0  2226 2024-05-01     2576
7  2024-06  29     49    0  2418 2024-06-01     2467
```

You can however speed up this operation using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to vectorise the `if` expression:

```
forec_pivot2['new_col'] = forec_pivot2['Japan'] + forec_pivot2['MTO'] + \
    np.where(forec_pivot2['Month_date'] < d1, 0, forec_pivot2['ROW'])
```

The result is the same as your loop code produces.